# SharePoint 2007 Creating Date Look up Field

Tags: sharepoint, date

I am trying to set a field in SP to a certain value, which depends on certain date values and one field where we require a list of dates to be entered by the user, not a standard date picker. Now the fly in the ointment here is the look up field for the list of dates we require. I initially made a list of dates, in string format but we need to compare dates so that solution is too messy.

We also need a rolling/dynamic date comparison for some of the calculations, so for instance users pick a date from the list of dates and it is compared against the first and last day of the next three months (that is the values in the date list drop down). I initially made calculated date columns with the old 'Today' trick and text conversion of the date columns so that I could do a workflow to check if the picked date (text format) was equal to the respective date (text) value.

I quickly realised this will fail spectacularly when the month changes as the date columns (calculated from the illustrious 'Today') will not update for existing records so if someone changes a date from an existing record it will be looking at potentially the previous month or before, depending on how long it has been there, but I always require a list of six dates (first and last day) from the current and next 2 months.

Can anyone suggest how to get:

- A look up column with a list of six dates that are in date format not
  string
- Six variables/columns that have corresponding dates for
  current and next two months that automatically updates to reflect the
  new month, and so increments all the dates one month forward and
  updating the day and year dynamically

OR

- Some sort of work flow comparison where I can check the range that the date is in from look up, although I still need to check against these dates or between these dates anyway.

This is a real head scratcher and would really appreciate some help with this as I cannot find any non-complex code solutions, I do not have time to learn new languages if possible. I only have basic SQL/Excel/Access/SP coding knowledge and some VB/Java and a taste of some other coding platforms.

Thanks

A

Answer (score 0):

You might try to avoid using look up fields. since you need a field that has six possible calculated values you do not need to store them anywhere. You might try to implement a custom field that has an Edit Rendering template that actually calculates the possible values for your dropdown and allows users to pick these six values. when the value of the field is saved you could store not the actual value from the dropdown but a code that represents the value, for example if a user selects the first date of the current month the code could be "a", if the user selects the last date of the following month - the code is "d", etc. so you would use codesthat will be recalculated into dates according to the current date in your workflow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have more information on doing that in SP designer, I have only been able to create a simple workflow but am struggling to find examples of how to do custom fields etc?

Comment: Since you're tring to avoid coding I will not insist on you using Visual Studio 2010 to create a custom field ;) So you can try to do the following: 1) instead a date field add a text field (you will store custom formatted  info there) 2) implement custom Edit, Display, New forms 3) Implement XSLT for you list view to render data as a required date instead. In your workflows you will compare not the date values but string values, like "if FieldValue == 'd' then do some action for the end of the next month". P.S. I'd use the Visual Studio approach as more bugfree and less difficult.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't make sense to me I am quite a newbie all said to this whole sharepoint and visual studio. I need dummy instructions please! How do I manipulate the website in VS